# Horizontal menu with animating drop-right function

Tags: css

I would like to create a horizontal menu with an animating effect when hovering on first level items like this:

```css
.nav {
  float: right;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav ul li {
    position: relative;
}

.nav > ul > li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;  
}

.nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  color: #6E6C6C;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.nav ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: none;
  width: 110px;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.nav > ul > li > a {
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
  width: auto;
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;

}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List Sub-Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List Sub-Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List Sub-Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List Sub-Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List Sub-Item 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here i have the problem that when i hover out the first level item it returns to it's initial state.
How can i approach this problem? Should i use flexbox?
Please provide me a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `.nav ul li a:hover` selector to `.nav ul li:hover > a`.

Updated snippet:

```css
.nav {
  float: right;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav ul li {
    position: relative;
}

.nav > ul > li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;  
}

.nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  color: #6E6C6C;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.nav ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: none;
  width: 110px;
}

.nav ul li:hover > a {
  color: #000;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.nav > ul > li > a {
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
  width: auto;
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;

}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List Sub-Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List Sub-Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List Sub-Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List Sub-Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List Sub-Item 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thank you Gothdo. Is there a way to animate the second level items from top to bottom? Also any responsive considerations about this navigation layout?